# Sort Tenors in finance notation using Java

Tags: java, comparator

I have list of Tenors

```
List<String> tenors =Arrays.asList("SPOT","1W","2W","10Y", "15Y", "1M", "1Y", "20Y", "2Y", "30Y", "3M", "5Y", "6M", "9M")
```

where M stands for month and Y stands for years. The correctly sorted order (ascending) would then be

```
["SPOT","1W","2W","1M", "3M", "6M", "9M", "1Y", "2Y", "5Y", "10Y", "15Y", "20Y", "30Y"]
```

How do I achieve this using Java?.Do i need to use custom comparators?

Comment: Are those supposed to be Strings? You're using single quotes, which is not valid Java syntax. Firstly, I would avoid using Strings and instead create a Tenor class, one that implements `Comparable<Tenor>`.

Comment: Yes, i modified to double quotes..

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but my main recommendation remains -- don't over-use Strings when creating a custom class would make much more sense. Otherwise this is either an anti-pattern or in the very least a common code "smell"

Comment: Fine.Any possible solutions for this query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static final Pattern D = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)([WMY])");
static final Map<String, Integer> R = Map.of("W", 7, "M", 30, "Y", 365);

static int days(String s) {
    Matcher m = D.matcher(s);
    return m.matches() ? Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)) * R.get(m.group(2)) : 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> tenors = Arrays.asList("SPOT", "1W", "2W", "10Y", "15Y", "1M", "1Y", "20Y", "2Y", "30Y", "3M", "5Y", "6M", "9M");
    Collections.sort(tenors, Comparator.comparingInt(s -> days(s)));
    System.out.println(tenors);
}
```

output:

```
[SPOT, 1W, 2W, 1M, 3M, 6M, 9M, 1Y, 2Y, 5Y, 10Y, 15Y, 20Y, 30Y]
```

Comment: Worth noting that you have made assumptions about the length of a month and a year which are not fixed length (it is the only way to solve this problem, but still). Your method also treats 30W and 7M as equivalent, so you may end up with non-deterministic output, depending on the input order. In a production system, you wouldn't want those 2 swapping positions arbitrarily, so a sensible thing to do is use length in days as a tie-breaker: e.g. M always comes after W if the value in days is equal.

Comment: (30W and 7M are not very common examples, but 30D and 1M certainly are. So if you were to extend this to include D = 1, the problem would be more likely to happen)

Answer (score 0):

A way to sort the strings with custom comparators (If you don't want to create a Tenor class):

```
List<String> tenors =Arrays.asList("SPOT","1W","2W","10Y", "15Y", "1M", "1Y", "20Y", "2Y", "30Y", "3M", "5Y", "6M", "9M");

//Define an order which enables you to sort by value, ex. W=1 < M=2
Map<String, Integer> map = Map.of("SPOT", 0, "W", 1, "M", 2, "Y", 3);

//remove digits to compare only the time-unit part
Comparator<String> byTime = Comparator.comparing(s -> map.get(s.replaceAll("\\d+","")));

//do oposite of the above: remove all non digit chars to compare the values
Comparator<String> byValue = Comparator.comparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("\\D+","")));

//chain comparators to sort as desired
tenors.sort(byTime.thenComparing(byValue));

System.out.println(tenors);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to give too much power to Strings and instead create a class that can hold values, such as Strings, but values with information, information that can be used, including used to compare one to the other.

For example, in this situation, I'd create a Tenor class, one that holds an int value as well as something to represent a duration (week, month, year, for example). Now I could use a String for the duration, but since there are only limited values that could work, it would be much better and much *safer* to use an enum to represent the duration. So, for instance, one could create an enum like so:

```
public enum Duration {
    SPOT("SPOT", 0), WEEK("W", 1), MONTH("M", 4), YEAR("Y", 52);    
    
    private Duration(String abbreviation, int weeks) {
        this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
        this.weeks = weeks;
    }

    private String abbreviation;
    private int weeks;
    
    public String getAbbreviation() {
        return abbreviation;
    }
    
    public int getWeeks() {
        return weeks;
    }
}
```

to represent our duration. Then the Tenor fields would look like:

```
public class Tenor {
    private int value;
    private Duration duration;
```

with getters, setters, toString and so on...

But we would also want to have Tenor implement the `Comparable` interface, or more specifically, the `Comparable<Tenor>` interface, and so this could look like so:

```
public class Tenor implements Comparable<Tenor> {
    private int value;
    private Duration duration;
    
    public Tenor(Duration duration) {
        this(duration, 0);
    }
    
    public Tenor(Duration duration, int value) {
        this.duration = duration;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Tenor o) {
        int weeks = value * duration.getWeeks();
        int otherWeeks = o.value * o.duration.getWeeks();
        return Integer.compare(weeks, otherWeeks);
    }
    
    // getters, setters, toString...
    
}
```

Here, we can calculate number of weeks for both the `this` `Tenor` as well as for the other, `o` Tenor parameter and directly compare them using `Integer.compare(...)`

I'd also want a method, perhaps a static method of the Tenor class, that converts a String to a Tenor. This would be a little tricky and would require use of regular expressions, as well as throwing an exception, preferably a "checked" exception, if the conversion when awry.

A testable version (that doesn't yet use a checked exception) could look like so:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class TenorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] tests = {"SPOT", "1W","2W","10Y", "15Y", "1M", "1Y", "20Y", "2Y", "30Y", "3M", "5Y", "6M", "9M"};
        
        List<Tenor> tenors = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String text : tests) {
            tenors.add(Tenor.toTenor(text));
        }
        
        System.out.println(tenors); 
        
        // sort the collection and then repeat the printout
        Collections.sort(tenors);
        System.out.println(tenors);
    }
}
```

```
public class Tenor implements Comparable<Tenor> {
    private int value;
    private Duration duration;
    
    public Tenor(Duration duration) {
        this(duration, 0);
    }
    
    public Tenor(Duration duration, int value) {
        this.duration = duration;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Tenor o) {
        int weeks = value * duration.getWeeks();
        int otherWeeks = o.value * o.duration.getWeeks();
        return Integer.compare(weeks, otherWeeks);
    }
    
    public Duration getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
    
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (duration == Duration.SPOT) {
            return Duration.SPOT.getAbbreviation();
        } else {
            return Integer.toString(value) + duration.getAbbreviation();
        }
    }
    
    public static Tenor toTenor(String text) {
        Tenor tenor = null;
        int value = -1;
        Duration duration = null;
        text = text.trim().toUpperCase();
        String regex = "(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)";
        String[] tokens = text.split(regex);
        if (tokens.length == 1) {
            if (tokens[0].equals(Duration.SPOT.getAbbreviation())) {
                tenor = new Tenor(Duration.SPOT, 0);
            } 
        } else if (tokens.length == 2) {
            try {
                value = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
                for (Duration d : Duration.values()) {
                    if (d.getAbbreviation().equals(tokens[1])) {
                        duration = d;
                    }
                }
                
                if (duration != null) {
                    tenor = new Tenor(duration, value);
                }
                
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // ignore
            }
        }
        
        if (tenor != null) {
            return tenor;
        } else {
            // TODO: change this to a custom checked exception

            String txt = "For text \"" + text + "\"";
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(txt);
        }
    }
}
```

So, on running this program, I see this output:

```
[SPOT, 1W, 2W, 10Y, 15Y, 1M, 1Y, 20Y, 2Y, 30Y, 3M, 5Y, 6M, 9M]
[SPOT, 1W, 2W, 1M, 3M, 6M, 9M, 1Y, 2Y, 5Y, 10Y, 15Y, 20Y, 30Y]
```

The first line showing the unsorted output, and the second line showing the sorted

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime you can take an OOP approach and model each element to an object:

```
public class Example {

    static class Tenor {

        private int amount;
        private ChronoUnit unit;
        private String createdFromString;

        public Tenor(int amount, ChronoUnit unit, String createdFromString) {
            this.amount = amount;
            this.unit = unit;
            this.createdFromString = createdFromString;
        }

        Duration getDuration() {
            return unit.getDuration().multipliedBy(amount);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return createdFromString;
        }
    }

    static class TenorFactory {
        private static final Map<String, ChronoUnit> stringToUnitMap = new HashMap<>();
        static {
            stringToUnitMap.put("M", ChronoUnit.MONTHS);
            stringToUnitMap.put("Y", ChronoUnit.YEARS);
            stringToUnitMap.put("W", ChronoUnit.WEEKS);
        }

        static Tenor create(String tenorString) {
            if ("SPOT".equals(tenorString))
                return new Tenor(0, ChronoUnit.MILLIS, tenorString);

            int value = Integer.parseInt(tenorString.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
            String unitAsString = tenorString.replaceAll("[^A-Z]", "");
            ChronoUnit unit = stringToUnitMap.get(unitAsString);
            if (unit == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown chrono unit:" + unitAsString);
            return new Tenor(value, unit, tenorString);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> tenors = Arrays.asList("SPOT", "1W", "2W", "10Y", "15Y", "1M", "1Y", "20Y", "2Y", "30Y",
                "3M", "5Y", "6M", "9M");

        //@formatter:off
        List<String> sortedTenors = tenors.stream().map(TenorFactory::create)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Tenor::getDuration))
                .map(Tenor::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        //@formatter:on

        System.out.println(sortedTenors);
    }
}
```

If you do not understand what the `stream()...` lines do, well... you can do it with a traditional for-loop by yourself.